# JavaScript add css to dynamic table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to align my one table cell text to right i do it like this:

```
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell4.css("text-align","right");
```

but i get:

```
TypeError: cell4.css is not a function

cell4.css("text-align","right");
```

Comment: We need a bit more context here to know whats going on... What's `row`? What's `insertCell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$(cell4).css("text-align","right");` to make sure you're calling .css on a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You must use textAling instead text-align

```
cell4.textAlign = "right";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell4.style.textAlign = "right";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp) , the JavaScript syntax is object.**style**.textAlign="right"